# Multiple App Store Pages with one Account

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I do custom iOS development for small companies.  These companies have me completely manage their apps.  The problem is that these companies apps show up on my company's App Store Account.  Example: There is a mix of apps on the "More from this Developer" line.

I would like a way to manage all the apps I create in one itunesconnect account but have the apps deployed in such a way that they do not appear to be related and the "Developer" appears to be my client instead of me.

Is there a way to do that?

The purpose is to hold down the pain of switching accounts to manage the release cycle of the apps.

Answer (score 0):

Each company will need to setup their own developer account (as an organization account) over at https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/

After that, they can invite you/your Apple ID as an `admin` and you can switch teams on App Store Connect / Apple Developer Center. With admin rights you have full access to setup everything for those customers and they also retain all IP, analytics data etc.